# Independent cycles in undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the algorithm that allows me to determine the independent cycles in an undirected graph.
For example, in the figure below:
The independent cycles:
[2-12-4-5-13-2]
[4-5-6-4]
[4-10-11-7-6-4]
[image]
Thanxs

Comment: What's your definition of an *independent cycle*?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a spanning tree and consider the graphs you get by adding a single edge of your graph.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Israel

Suppose we have the graph below .Using your method, I will get 2 cycles : [8-2-3-8] and [8-2-4-5-3-8].

[image]

But I want to get [8-2-3-8] and [2-4-5-3-2].

[image]
<sub>(source: [0zz0.com](http://www6.0zz0.com/2014/09/01/00/470152171.jpg))</sub>